# In a Firefox extension, if I open a tab using a custom scheme, how do I close it, because my extension is not authorized for that scheme pattern?

Tags: firefox-addon, chromium, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a custom scheme mapped on my Windows machine: "dbn".

So, when I put `dbn:/some/arguments` in the Firefox address bar (or click on such a link), it launches in another application. This works great.

However, in a Firefox extension, I don't know how to "call" or "activate" this custom scheme except by opening a new tab, like this:

```
browser.tabs.create({ url: 'dbn:/some/arguments' });
```

That works fine, except now I have an open tab with `dbn:/some/arguments` as the URL. I have attempted to subsequently close it from my extension, but I can't because:

> Error: Missing host permission for the tab

My extension doesn't have permissions for that "host."

I have tried to give it permissions via a `match_patterns` value of `dbn:*` but that throws an error when I try to reload the extension because those values apparently have to use one of the expected schemes (http, https, ftp, etc.).

I end up just having to close the tab manually, which isn't terrible, but is clearly sub-optimal.

So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to "call" a URL in such a way to activate a custom-mapped scheme on Windows without opening a tab? The only way I could think of doing this in such a way that it would activate my mapped command was to open a tab, but are there other ways?
2. If opening a new tab is the only way to do this, how do I close the tab I just opened without having the permissions problem I mention above?

**Update**

I don't think it's permissions anymore. The Promise simply won't resolve.

```
browser.tabs.create({ url: "some/url" })
    .then(tab => console.error("I never get here"));
```

I've debugged up, down, and sideways. The new tab opens, and I can write to the log all around that operation, but the code in `then` just doesn't execute, no matter what I put in there. I tried to trap an error with `try...catch`, but that didn't trap anything.

I now think that permission above was coming from a different extension, not my extension. I don't think this has anything to do with the host.

Answer (score 0):

AFA custom schemes, there is an open bug: [Extend match patterns to handle custom protocol schemes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1572187)

You can [tabs.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/remove) a tab by its ID  which you get from [tabs.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create).

```js
async function fun() {

  // note this is async
  const tab = await browser.tabs.create({url: 'dbn:/some/arguments'});

  // later remove it
  browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);
} 

// or
browser.tabs.create({url: 'dbn:/some/arguments'})
.then(tab => {
  // do what is needed


  // later remove it
  browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);
});
```

*Update:*
Regarding the Promise, there is not enough information to pinpoint the issue.

Which permissions have been set?
Where is the code running?

Use `catch` to get more info about the Promise failure:

```js
browser.tabs.create({url: "some/url"})
.then(tab => console.log(`Created new tab: ${tab.id}`))
.catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: See my edit to the question. It turns out that the Promise just isn't executing/resolving.

Comment: Okay, that caught the error. Here it is: "Cannot send function call result: other side closed connection." I did some searching around that. There are lots of things that can cause it, apparently.

Comment: @Deane As mentioned, there is not enough details in your post. If action is started for example from a pop-up ie browserAction/pageAction, and pop-up is closed, then when the async promise is fulfilled, there is no reference for it since the page that called it has been closed.